# accessing mdb database when website deployed to host provider

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, web

I changed my host provider from godaddy to webhosting world, and now suffering the problem regarding the access of mdb database via vb code of my aspx page.

The following is my code created using Microsoft visual web developer software. It works well when run in my computer, and when deployed to godaddy. but when i uploaded it to webhosting world, it failed to work.

I contacted the support team of my new host provider, still can't resolve the problem. would appreciate if anyone can enlighten me....

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim cn As OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        'test write
        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/number_database.mdb"))
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand()
        cmd.Connection = cn
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO testing (a_name, a_id) VALUES (@a_name, @a_id)"
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_name", TextBox1.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a_id", TextBox2.Text)


        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()

        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""


        'test read
        Dim my_namelist(100), myid(100) As String
        Dim counter_read As Integer


        cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/number_database.mdb"))
            cn.Open()
        cn.Open()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM testing ", cn)

        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Do While reader.Read()
            my_namelist(counter_read) = reader.GetString(1)
            myid(counter_read) = reader.GetString(2)

            counter_read = counter_read + 1
        Loop
        reader.Close()

        TextBox3.Text = "database list" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        For a = 0 To counter_read
            TextBox3.Text = TextBox3.Text & my_namelist(a) & vbTab & vbTab & myid(a) & vbNewLine

        Next 

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: "failed to work"? Not much. Is this a 32-bit environment and is Jet.OLEDB.4.0 installed?

Comment: Yes. It's jet.oledb.4.0.... may I know how to resolve the problem? Thanks in advance....

Comment: If the application pool where the site is running under has "Enable 32-bit applications" set to "False", Jet.OLEDB.4.0 won't be seen. And there is no 64-bit version of Jet.OLEDB.4.0.

Comment: hi sir, can u elaborate more what you mean? what should i do to fix the problem? thanks in advance

Comment: You can configure your application to run under 32-bit only. If that doesn't work, ask the hosting provider if they can configure the environment to run 32-bit applications.